# Using type tag in logback configuration for logback-elasticsearch-appender

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, logback

As everyone can see in their [GitHub page](https://github.com/internetitem/logback-elasticsearch-appender) there's an inner *type* tag for the *property* tag which is supposed to tell Elasticsearch if the value of that property should be written as a string, number... in the resulting JSON (at least that's what I understand):

> type (optional, default String): type of the field on the resulting
>   JSON message. Possible values are: String, int, float and boolean.

But I can't make it work.

This is the snippet of my logback.xml file:

```
<appender name="ELASTIC" class="com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAppender">
...
    <property>
        <name>elapsed time (ms)</name>
        <value>%X{elapsedTime}</value>
        <type>int</type>
    </property>
...
</appender>
```

and I'm configuring logback using JoranConfigurator:

```
String logConfigurationPath = "logback.xml";
if (logConfigurationPath != null) {
  LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

  try {
    JoranConfigurator config = new JoranConfigurator();

    config.setContext(context);

    context.reset();

    config.doConfigure(logConfigurationPath);
  } catch (JoranException je) {

  }
  StatusPrinter.printInCaseOfErrorsOrWarnings(context);
}
```

Logback configures OK, but when it tries to process that *type* tag I get an error:

```
testingdocker                | 09:46:13,134 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@68:23 - no applicable action for [type], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][properties][property][type]]
```

And Elastic set that tag in the resulting JSON as a String, as I can check in Kibana.

How can I use that tag properly so I get number types in Kibana from Logback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the appender.

If you see Property.java, you will see:

```
public void setType(String type) {
    try {
        this.type = Enum.valueOf(Type.class, type.toUpperCase());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        this.type = Type.STRING;
    }
}
```

So, if you set something that is not in Enum, it will use String. This is fine. So we can see about Type:

```
public enum Type {
     STRING, INT, FLOAT, BOOLEAN
}
```

And I think here you are problem! ElasticSearch do not accept the type "int", but "integer".

More information about data types:

- [Elasticsearch 2.3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/number.html)
- [Elasticsearch 6.X](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/number.html)